# Help recovering broken OS (permissions issue)

Tags: 12.04, permissions, sudo

(At the bottom there is an important update.)

I was doing experiments in order to backup a remote account to my local system, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm not confident with duplicity and probably, due to wrong syntax, some local files have been replaced with remote files. This is just a supposition, I'm not sure this is the real cause of OS corruption. The corruption happened after experimenting with backups, so I think I did something wrong at this regard.

I was aware there was a problem when I tried to access a command using `sudo`:

```
$ sudo ls
sudo: unable to open /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

This is how /etc/sudoers looks like:

```
$ ls -ald /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 788 Oct 2 18:30 /etc/sudoers
```

At this point I tried to reboot and now this is the message I get:

```
The system is running in low graphics mode.
Your screen, graphics card and input device
settings could not be detected correctly.
You will need to configure these yourself.
```

I tried to follow the wizard to configure these settings, but without luck (the system prevents me going on when I press "Next").

The thing that makes me a bit less worried is that all the data on the disk seems readable and I'm able to access them using a live cd. I run memtest and RAM seems to be OK.

Do you have any idea about how to recover my system? I'm very glad to provide further information, just let me know what info could be helpful.

**UPDATE.** The issue is about wrong permissions and this is how I discovered: I mounted the root partition of the broken OS on `/mnt/broken/` (live CD) and did `ls /mnt/broken/`. I got a permission denied error, while I expected to have the directory listing. I had to do `sudo ls /mnt/broken/` and this worked. Thus without having root permission via sudo it's impossible to access the root of broken os.

The current output of `ls -ld /mnt/broken/` is:

```
drwxr-x--- 29 1000 812 4096 2012-12-08 21:58 /mnt/broken
```

Any thoughts on how to restore the old (working) set of permissions?

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode from GRUB ? If yes then try logging in as root and run `pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`

Comment: and regarding the failsafe graphics have a look over here http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: @Gufran thanks. About your comment #1, I did what you suggested but it doesn't change anything. /etc/sudoers already had these permissions. Another thing, in recovery mode from GRUB, the filesystem was mounted readonly. I had to use a live cd and mount the partition from there, then run pkexec.

Answer (score 1):

If the file system was mounted readonly please run `mount -n -o remount,rw /` to mount the root with read/write support. Alright, Lets Move on.

You can use `pkexec` as an alternative to `sudo` for the time being.

First of all ensure you have root privilege by `groups <username>` and look for `sudo` in output.
If your account is not in group `sudo` then add it to sudo group by `usermod -a -G sudo <username>`

then check the permissions on **/etc** directory and see if it has permissions set above or at least **544** that means you can at least read from it.
Use `chmod 751 /etc` to set proper permissions
Then again `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` to set proper permissions for sudoers file
Then verify that `lsattr /etc/sudoers` shows at least `- - e - /etc/sudoers`
Use `chattr +e /etc/sudoers` if you cannot see "**e**" in output from last command.

### Syntax Error ?

If problem still persists then you might want to look into the sudoers file for any syntax error or just export the content to a file by `cat /etc/sudoers >> /home/<username>/sudoers.txt` and show it to us.

### Go Advance !

I will not recommend this if you dont have enough experience with linux but you always have an option to re-install the sudo package with `apt-get install --reinstall sudo` while logged in as root in recovery mode and then configure the sudoers file with `visudo` editor **only**.

First match the uncommented content in sudoers file with the content written below and if necessary make changes wherever you can.

In case you decide to reinstall and configure the `sudo` you'd basically need to add **only** this to the sudoer file if not already present:

**`Defaults    env_reset

Defaults    mail_badpass

Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`**

As a final note and warning, You have to edit the file with only `visudo /etc/sudoers` as root and after you are finished editing the file set proper permissions for it i.e. **440**

Comment: This procedure would fix the whole thing. But I did a sad discovery, please have a look at how my question changed... I think I have to repair the permissions of my filesystem, admitting it's possible.

Comment: Well, I guess the permissions are so for the live cd user which is 'live_user' or something like that, I'm not sure. You can verify the situation by logging into recovery mode as root.